# How can I prevent debugger from stepping into header files like "@file ext/new_allocator.h " and "@file bits/vector.tcc" in codelite?

Tags: c++, debugging, stl, gdb, codelite

This is my code.When I step out of the move constructor,the debugger steps into weird looking functions(I'm new to programming) and files that are GNU extensions of the standard c++ library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Move {
private:
    int *data;
public:
    void set_data_value(int d) { *data = d; }
    int get_data_value() { return *data; }
    // Constructor
    Move(int d);
    // Copy Constructor
    Move(const Move &source);
    Move(Move &&source);
    // Destructor
    ~Move();
};

 Move::Move(int d)  {
    data = new int;
    *data = d;
    cout << "Constructor for: " << d << endl;
}


Move::Move(const Move &source)
    : Move {*source.data} {
        cout << "Copy constructor  - deep copy for: " << *data << endl;
}

//Move ctor
Move::Move(Move &&source) 
    : data {source.data} {
        source.data = nullptr;
        cout << "Move constructor - moving resource: " << *data << endl;
}

Move::~Move() {
    if (data != nullptr) {
        cout << "Destructor freeing data for: " << *data << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Destructor freeing data for nullptr" << endl;
    }
    delete data;
}

int main(){
    vector<Move> vec;

    vec.push_back(Move{10});

    vec.push_back(Move{20});
    vec.push_back(Move{30});
    vec.push_back(Move{40});
     vec.push_back(Move{50});
    vec.push_back(Move{60});
    vec.push_back(Move{70});
    vec.push_back(Move{80});

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to avoid these files and functions since I have no idea what they are yet.Do you have any solutions?Thanks.

Comment: These are not extensions but implementation files. Unfortunately GDB does not provide a good way to skip them in a single-step mode. The [`skip` command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Skipping-Over-Functions-and-Files.html) does NOT do a good job but you can try it if you want.

Comment: Which files and functions do you want to avoid? Please name them!

Answer (score -3):

Read the documentation of [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). Compile your C++ code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`

Read carefully about GDB [breakpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Breakpoints.html), e.g. the `tbreak` command.

Notice that both GDB and GCC are [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), and you are allowed to download their source code and study then improve their code.

Take also inspiration from the source code of existing open source projects like [FLTK](https://fltk.org/), [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/), [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/)....

GDB can be [extended](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Extending-GDB.html), and GCC can be [extended](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html), with your plugins.

See also the [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) project (and the [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) static source code analyzer above GCC) and the [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) static analyzer. If interested, contact me by email to `<basile.starynkevitch@cea.fr>`

See also [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and some C++ standard like [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) or better.

Consider using the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) (whose source code you can study, since it is open source).

Be aware of the [C++ rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html).